# How to move text within <div> (vertically and horizontally)?

Tags: html, css, text

Complete beginner here! I'm trying to move some text (H3) a little bit to the right in my webpage and not sure how to do it? Also should I be using CSS or is there a way for HTML to do it?

I've been trying to find similar questions but they all revolve around centering the text and don't allow much option for positioning it specifically.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I will gladly help you out, but in order to this, you need to create an example.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y problem but we have absolutely no way of knowing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option #1 with CSS (for all H3):

```css
h3 {
  padding-left:100px; //pixels how many you want
}
```

```html
<h3>Text Text Text Text Text Text </h3>
<h3>Text Text Text Text Text Text </h3>
```

Option #2 with html (only for this one H3):

```html
<h3>Text Text Text Text Text Text </h3>
<h3 style="padding-left:100px;">Text Text Text Text Text Text </h3>
```

Option #3 with CSS (only for this one H3):

```css
.h3-class-name {
  padding-left:100px; //pixels how many you want
}
```

```html
<h3>Text Text Text Text Text Text </h3>
<h3 class="h3-class-name">Text Text Text Text Text Text </h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding/margin to move your text :

```
padding-left: 10px //how many pixel you want to move
or 
margin-left: 10px //how many pixel you want to move
```

Answer (score 0):

To move the text you have to use CSS, however you dont have to create a new css file. You can use inline css instead like this:

```html
<h1 style="padding-left: 20px;">I moved the heading by 20px</h1>
```

You can find more examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css_padding.asp).